# VBA code that reads from specific column data

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA Code creates the PT and the chart automatically.

I would like my chart to read from the "Grand Total" column. It defaults and reads from the first column "Closed".

Here is my code below:

```
Sub PT_C_RiskType_Status_test()
'
' PT_C_RiskType_Status_test Macro
'


    'Defining the variables

    Dim pc As PivotCache
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim sh As Shape
    Dim ch As Chart


    Set pc = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:="DataSource", _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15)


    Set ws = Sheets.Add

    ws.Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    Range("A3:D9").Select


     'Create the pivot table

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ws.Name & "!R3C1", _
                                TableName:="Pivottable")


     'Adding the data fields

    pt.AddDataField _
        Field:=pt.PivotFields("Status"), _
        Function:=XlConsolidationFunction.xlCount

     'Adding the fields


        pt.AddFields _
        RowFields:="Risk Type", _
        ColumnFields:="Status"


    'Adding chart

    Set sh = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(XlChartType:=XlChartType.xlPie, _
                Width:=200, Height:=200)


    Set ch = sh.Chart

End Sub
```

Please advise.

Comment: Check this part: `!R3C1`, that's Column 1. Change that to whatever number you need I believe.

Comment: R3 is the row 3, the beginning of the pivot table and C1 is the first column of the PT .. Changing it won't change the default series of the chart

Comment: I think you need to reselect the data you want to chart after you create the pivot table.